# .html() adding styling with html() in query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to add styling into my website using `.html()`.

I have tried:

**jQuery:**

```
if ($('#checkbox:checked') > 0) {
    $("body").html("
        <style>
            .selected{
                background-image: url('http://www.website.com');
            }
        </style>
    ");
}
```

But it gives me an error saying: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`

Comment: A string literal cannot span over multiple lines unless you put `\ ` at the end of each line. And also `$('#checkbox:checked')` returns an array instead of a number.

Comment: Here's an idea. Include the styles you want to activate in your main stylesheet, but prefix them all with `body.something`, then call `$('body').toggleClass('something');` to turn them on or off. I'm not sure of what you're going for but there might be an easier approach if we knew more.

Comment: @RyanBurnette thanks for the idea but I can't use that because my link will be including some php in it

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 so do I change that to `== true` ?

Comment: Then I'd go the inline style route from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27221550/2535178). Don't forget that you can use PHP to write the JavaScript onto the page.

Comment: @imbondbaby You can't compare an array with `>` or `==`. You can but it doesn't make sense. Add `.length` at the end since you are comparing its length, not its pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, to use multiline string in JavaScript, you have to put backslashes to the end of each line.
Example:

```
var str = "This\
           is\
           multiline\
           sting.";
```

Also, if you want to ADD html to `body`, not to replace it, do it in that way:

```
if ($('#checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
    $("body").append("\
        <style>\
            .selected{\
                background-image: url('http://www.website.com');\
            }\
        </style>\
   ");
}
```

(I added `.length` to your selector, because you can not compare 0 with array)

I didn't tested, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

**SIMPLY CLEAN**

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function () {
    (this.checked) ? bgVal='url("../images/picture.jpg")' : bgVal='default';
    $(".selected").css('background-image', bgVal);
});
```

Your default value needs to be specified in the `.selected` class.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `$('#checkbox').is(':checked')`?

Comment: You could do that too.  There are many ways to go about this.

Comment: And you might need to wrap it in `$('#checkbox').on('change', function () {});` to fire off when it changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if( $('#checkbox:checked').length > 0 ) {
    $("body").append("\
        <style>\
            .selected{\
                background-image: url('http://www.website.com');\
            }\
        </style>\
    ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should make your script in single line to make it work :

```
if ($('#checkbox:checked') > 0) {
    $("body").html("<style>.selected{ background-image: url('http://www.website.com');     } </style> ");
}
```

or you can add `slashes` to the end of each line.